# AngularJS form in develop module of dotnetnuke 7

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dotnetnuke

I'm developing a dotnetnuke 7 module using AngularJS.
Here is my code in View.ascx:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<h2>Validation Example</h2>

<form  ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="validateCtrl"
name="myForm" novalidate>

<p>Username:<br>
  <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required>
  <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
  <span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
  </span>
</p>

<p>Email:<br>
  <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required>
  <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
  <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
  <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
  </span>
</p>

<p>
  <input type="submit"
  ng-disabled="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid ||
  myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
</p>

</form>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('validateCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.user = 'John Doe';
        $scope.email = 'john.doe@gmail.com';
    });
</script>
```

The code is copied from W3School but it seems that the AngularJS is not working well. Here is my View's screenshot:
[image]

I have tried an AngularSJ simple example and it working good likes:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="firstName='John'">

<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"></p>
<p>You wrote: {{ firstName }}</p>

</div>
```

[image]

Why is my first block of code not working? Are there any issues regarding the "form" tag in my module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form tag is certainly an issue when running within DNN/ASP.NET Webforms.  I did a tutorial on [DNNHero.com](http://www.dnnhero.com/) on building [Angular applications as DNN modules](http://www.dnnhero.com/video/introduction-and-angular-concepts).

Two pieces of advice:

1. Use a div tag to add your angular controller directives:

`<div id="userForm" ng-controller="validateCtrl" ng-init="init(<%=this.ModuleId%>)">`

2. Don't hard-code the ng-app directive in your html. Instead use the bootstrap method for attaching your app.

`<script type="text/javascript">
        angular.element(document).ready(function () { 
            var moduleContainer = document.getElementById('userForm'); 
             angular.bootstrap(moduleContainer, ["myApp"]);
        });
 </script>`

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your answer, i have already tried your 2 pieces of advice but the validation of AngularJS still not working.Can you put here a completed View.ascx.
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that DNN already includes the `<form>` tag (via Default.aspx), and nesting form tags isn't permitted.

A solution is to use `<ng-form>` as a substitute. eg:

```
...
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl">
  <ng-form name="myForm">
    <p>Username:
      <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required>
      <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
        <span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
    </p>
  </ng-form>
</div>
...
```

Also, you'll want to turn off HTML 5 default form validation since you're using Angular validation methods (this query works in DNN):

```
$(function() {
  $('#Form').attr('novalidate', 'novalidate');
});
```

Further reading:

[ngForm directive](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/api/ng/directive/ngForm) in AngularJS docs

[Forms](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/guide/forms): Official AngularJS docs have better examples

Please be aware that the W3School example does not use best practices, and will introduce bad habits for the inexperienced (specifically, it doesn't include a '.' in ng-model which help avoid potential parent/child scope issues down the track.  See the Forms examples in the link for a more robust approach.)

Answer (score 1):

Can you do what you need to do with DNN through its API? It is best to think of Angular applications as completely disconnected from the server, like an iOS or Android application would be. Templating through DNN and Angular is inviting pain. Who knows what your rendered HTML looks like - I'm sure DNN/ASP.NET mangles it.

If you can leverage DNN's API the right mindset would be "I'm building an Angular application that happens to use DNN for persistence".